# CMenu::InsertMenu - обработка сообщения

Tags: c++, mfc

Как обработать сообщение, посылаемое из меню приложения, к которому я пишу плагин? Вставляю пункт меню с помощью **CMenu::InsertMenu**.

**Resource.h**

```
#define ID_EXPCATXML        100
```

**Plugin.h**

```
class Plugin : public CFrameWnd
{
public:
    Plugin();

protected:
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(Plugin)

public:
    virtual ~Plugin();

public:
    // Export function
    EXPORTKDE BOOL OnAppStartAfter(long CallParamBlock);
public:
    // Generate message map functions
    afx_msg void OnExportCatalogXML();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

**Plugin.cpp**

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(Plugin, CFrameWnd)
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(Plugin, CFrameWnd)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_EXPCATXML, &Plugin::OnExportCatalogXML)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL Plugin::OnAppStartAfter(long CallParamBlock)
{
    CWnd *pMain = CWnd::FindWindow(NULL, L"MobiScript");
    if (pMain != NULL)
    {
        CMenu *pMenu = NULL;
        pMenu = pMain->GetMenu()->GetSubMenu(0)->GetSubMenu(6);
        if (pMenu != NULL)
        {
            pMenu->InsertMenu(0, MF_BYPOSITION, ID_EXPCATXML, _T("Catalog to XML\tCtrl+E"));
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

void Plugin::OnExportCatalogXML()
{
    AfxMessageBox(L"Test");
}
```

На момент выбора встроенного меню не выполняется обработчик *OnExportCatalogXML*. Насколько я понимаю, встроенное меню отправляет сообщение для (*CMainFrame*) приложения, к которому доступа нет.

Я подумал, что если можно получить указатель на дочернее окно "MobiScript", то, возможно, есть способ обработать сообщение элемента.

Любые идеи приветствуются, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этой цели есть специальная функция [CWnd::SubclassWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wt95892.aspx)

```
bool Plugin::OnAppStartAfter(long CallParamBlock)
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    SessionId = app->StartSessionFromCallParams(&CallParamBlock);
    if (SessionId != 0)
    {
        m_pWnd = CWnd::FindWindow(_T("#32770"), _T("MobiScript"));
        HWND hWnd = m_pWnd->m_hWnd;

        if (m_pWnd != NULL)
        {
            m_pMenu = m_pWnd->GetMenu()->GetSubMenu(0)->GetSubMenu(6);
            if (m_pMenu != NULL)
            {
                m_pMenu->InsertMenu(0, MF_BYPOSITION, ID_EXPCATXML, _T("Catalog to XML\tCtrl+E"));
            }
        }
        plugin.SubclassWindow(hWnd);
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас нет доступа к окну, вы можете переопределить оконную процедуру, т.е.

1. Получить указатель на старый обработчик с помощью `GetWindowLong(GWL_WNDPROC)` (либо с помощью пункта 2).
2. Задать свой обработчик `SetWindowLong(GWL_WNDPROC)`, она возвращает старый обработчик.
3. В своем обработчике, ловить сообщение `WM_COMMAND` с вашим айдишником (`ID_EXPCATXML`), во всех остальных случаях вызывать старую функцию-обработчик.

Но это очень кривой способ. Обычно такое делается через [SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g53wsfp5kpr68hm/SDK%20KitchenDraw65_RU.doc?dl=0).

Чем вас не устроил вариант с [InsertMobiScriptMenuItem](https://github.com/INTITY/KDE/blob/master/src/KDE/Plugin.cpp#L34) ?

Comment: Функция InsertMobiscriptMenuItem не позволяет вставить субменю.

Comment: 1. Получить указатель на обработчик: 
`DWORD nWnd = GetWindowLong(pMain->GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_WNDPROC);`
2. Задать свой обработчик:
`DWORD pWnd = SetWindowLong(pMain->GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_WNDPROC, nWnd);` (возможно что еще передается в качестве параметра `dwNewLong`)
3. Вы имели ввиду переопределение `OnCmdMsg`?

Comment: Пишите свою функцию `LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND   hwnd,UINT   uMsg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam
);` (глобальную или статическую), устанавливаете ее с помощью `SetWindowLong(pMain->GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_WNDPROC, WindowProc); `. Внутри `WindowProc` обрабатываете случай `uMsg ==WM_COMMAND`. В конце вызываете старый обработчик с помощью `CallWindowProc`