# CWnd::WindowProc - переопределение функции

Tags: c++, mfc

Возможно переопределить функцию `CWnd::WindowProc` для обработки сообщений внешнего приложения, или данная функция используется как вспомогательная для объектов `CWnd`?

Определение оконной процедуры **WindowProc** (WinAPI)

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(
HWND hwnd,
UINT message,
WPARAM wParam,
LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Определение оконной процедуры **AfxWndProc** (MFC)

```
LRESULT CALLBACK AfxWndProc(
HWND hWnd, 
UINT nMsg,
WPARAM wParam, 
LPARAM lParam)
{
    //special message which identifies the window as using
    AfxWndProc
        if (nMsg == WM_QUERYAFXWNDPROC)
            return 1;

    // all other messages route through message map
    CWnd* pWnd = CWnd::FromHandlePermanent(hWnd);
    ASSERT(pWnd != NULL);
    ASSERT(pWnd->m_hWnd == hWnd);

    return AfxCallWndProc(pWnd, hWnd, nMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Как правильно организовать переопределение оконной процедуры приложения MFC? И если не сложно, поясните в чем принципиальная разница. Спасибо

Вопрос имеет отношение к [CMenu::InsertMenu - обработка сообщения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439805/cmenuinsertmenu-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы переопределить оконную процедуру, вам не обязательно для этого использовать средства MFC. Просто пишете свою функцию `WindowProc` и устанавливаете ее  с помощью `SetWindowLongPtr (hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)NewWndProc).`

```
WNDPROC pOrigProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr (hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)NewWndProc);

// Новая оконная процедура - глобальная или статическая (static) функция класса
LRESULT CALLBACK NewWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg) 
    {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            if ( LOWORD(wParam) == ID_EXPCATXML) 
            {
               MessageBox(NULL, "Hello", "", MB_OK);
                return 0;
            }
            break;
    }

    return CallWindowProc(pOrigProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

**AfxWndProc** является частным случаем обычной оконной процедуры

Comment: Если использовать ваш код без изменений, то возникает проблема приведения типа `(LONG)NewWndProc`, если сделать функцию статической, тогда ошибку `a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object`.

Comment: @ViteDecorum если вы создаете статическую функцию класса, пишите так:`SetWindowLongPtr (hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)&ClassName::NewWndProc);`, где `ClassName` - название вашего класса.

Comment: Результат аналогичный.

Answer (score 0):

Стандартная функция `CWnd::WondowProc` должна работать нормально, но я не могу понять где именно допускаю ошибку. Делал строго по инструкции:

**Plugin.h**

```
class Plugin : public CWnd
{
...
    protected:
        virtual LRESULT WindowProc(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
};
```

**Plugin.cpp**

```
LRESULT Plugin::WindowProc(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_EXPCATXML)
        {
            AfxMessageBox(L"Test");
            return 0;
        }
        break;
    }
    return CWnd::WindowProc(uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Вот похожий вопрос на [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/3f71c426-3bec-4f4e-b246-d423b3a8d7f5/wndproc-in-mfc)

Может необходимо добавить вспомогательный метод в карту сообщений класса Plugin?

Comment: функция должна быть статическая (`static`) а не virtual. Назовите ее как-то по-другому, чтобы не было конфликтов с функцией `CWnd::WindowProc`

Comment: Так если делать в контексте переопределения, функция должна быть определена как `virtual`, так описано в книге "Visual C++ и MFC", и примеры есть в сети.

Comment: Вы сами не понимаете, что делаете. Я вам предложил решение с использованием только winapi, никакого MFC. То есть класс `CWnd` вообще не при делах.

Comment: Полезная статья [Win32 против MFC - часть II](http://www.cyberguru.ru/cpp/mfc-versus-win32-pt2.html?showall=1)

Comment: Ваш метод не работает, и переопределить `CWnd::WindowProc` так же не получается. Я пробовал использовать функцию [GetMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx), но программа зависает.

Comment: Я задал аналогичный вопрос на форуме [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b95bdc48-6635-4b12-a59d-50135656499f/cwndwindowproc-override-function?forum=vcgeneral&prof=required), что характерно, ваш пример определили не рабочим. Странно то, что мне не удалось отладить приложение на базе Win32.

Comment: в том топике написан бред от начала до конца.

Comment: По крайней мере решение было найдено. Реализация, которую предложили Вы, не работает в отношении данного приложения. Если я допустил ошибку, поправьте меня. Хотя изначально данный вопрос не рассматривался, все же интересно, как это будет работать на базе Win32.